# How to Replace Multiple Special Character in Array in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

> This is My Form Input where I am using.

```
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <div class="form-group" id="title_of_class_form">
                            <label class="control-label">Title of Class: </label>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                              <input type="text" name="title_of_class" id="title_of_class" 
class="form-control"
                                autocomplete="off" />
                            </div>
                            <span style="color:red;font-size:12px;" id="errNm1"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <div class="form-group" id="classes_link">
                            <label class="control-label">Slug (Permalink): </label>
                            <div class="col-md-12" id="classes_link">
                              <input type="text" name="classes_link" placeholder="" val=""  
class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <span style="color:red;font-size:12px;" id="errNm1"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

> This is My Script Tag. In this code When I am replacing one String then my code is working but when I am using multiple Special characters the not working.

```
<script>
$('#title_of_class').keyup(function () {
 var title = $(this).val();
 title_link = title.replaceAll([' '], '-');
  title_link_data = title_link.replaceAll(['!','@','|','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','/','[',']','{','}',')','(','#','$','%','^','&','*','+','=',' '], '-');
  $('#classes_link input').val(title_link_data);
  console.log('#classes_link'+ title_link_data);
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to match only alphabets -

> Regex - /[^a-zA-Z]/g

```js
$('#title_of_class').keyup(function() {
  var title = $(this).val();
  title = title.replaceAll(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '-');
  $('#classes_link input').val(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group" id="title_of_class_form">
      <label class="control-label">Title of Class: </label>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="title_of_class" id="title_of_class" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
      </div>
      <span style="color:red;font-size:12px;" id="errNm1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group" id="classes_link">
      <label class="control-label">Slug (Permalink): </label>
      <div class="col-md-12" id="classes_link">
        <input type="text" name="classes_link" placeholder="" val="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <span style="color:red;font-size:12px;" id="errNm1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array with [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

> Syntax
>
> replaceAll(regexp, newSubstr)
> replaceAll(regexp, replacerFunction)
> replaceAll(substr, newSubstr)
> replaceAll(substr, replacerFunction)

Use `regex` instead

```js
a = '!"#$%&()0=~|^'
b = a.replaceAll(/[!,@,|,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,/,\[,\],{,},),(,#,$,%,^,&,*,+,=,| ]/g,'_')
console.log(b)
```

```
_"________~__
```